# Link remote site to visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, remote-desktop

i developed a site in my local laptop. The site is quite in an dvanced stage so i'd like to test it in the remote server where it will be once finished.
I use visual studio 2010 and i was asking myself if it was possible to leave the site in the server and go on developing it in my machine without loosing syncronization.
I mean, suppose i find a bug while navigating the site from my laptop. I would like to fix it without copying the site locally, and then put it back on the server manually.
Is this possible with Visual Studio 2010?

Some more info:
The site is hosted locally in C:\Mysite\ and in the server in C:\Mysite\ (the same directory).
I can connect to the server with remote desktop but the connection is authenticated (of course)... I wrote this in case it's useful information.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, by simply selecting `Open -> Website` and choosing `from FTP` or `Remote Site` in the directory browser.

However, just because you can doesn't mean you should! Keep a development and production copy separately.

Comment: As i said the development is pretty finshed, there are just a few bugs here and there to be fixed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Open VS2010 and then in File menu choose Open -> Website -> Remote site.
Then enter your remote address and it's done, you can work on your remote site as if it was local.

Answer (score 0):

it is not a good idea to publish your code directly to your server. However if you would like to do it, you can think of setting up continuous integration process. Whenever you commit the code, you can run a msbuild or nant script which gets latest code changes from source control and push to the server. You can also sse something like webdeploy... which ideal for web projects...